# Cannot interpolate data using Rbf in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I was trying to interpolate data using Rbf. The output data that I need is actually a single value. So I used something like

```
x=numpy.array([100])
y=numpy.array([200])
d=numpy.array([300])
rbfi=scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x,y,d)
```

But there was an error:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you try the example from the documentation first?

Comment: Using `Rbf` is a 2 step process - create an interpolator, then do the interpolation.  It doesn't make sense to interpolate on just one data point.

Answer (score 0):

Quite outdated but in case anyone wonders:

**`Rbf` requires at least 2 data points.**

```
x=numpy.array([100,120])
y=numpy.array([200,220])
d=numpy.array([300,100])
rbfi=scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x,y,d)

>>> print(rbfi)
<scipy.interpolate.rbf.Rbf object at 0x7fdac142b240>
```